# how to decide rootView in AppDelegate

Tags: objective-c, ios

I am learning iOS and developing my first iPone app. I want to add a feature to my app: if a user has login before, I want to redirect the user to the main view. otherwise, I want to redirect the user to the login view.

I have read [ios change storyboard default view controller at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610012/ios-change-storyboard-default-view-controller-at-run-time), but I am wondering whether I can write the code that decides the root view in AppDelegate. Therefore, I won't have a view that is never launched.

this is my code in AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];


    MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    if (userNeverLogin) {
       LoginViewController *rootVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
    return YES;
}
```

this code doesn't work (it will not trigger any error, but it will show nothing in the simulator). how should I revise it? Or it's impossible to do this feature in AppDelegate?

I am sorry that I am a newbie to iOS. I hope this question is not stupid.

Comment: it is possible to do this in the AppDelegate

Comment: @Brian Are you actually using a storyboard?

Comment: yes, I am using a storyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found out the answer from @followben in [Conditionally start at different places in storyboard from AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8451975/conditionally-start-at-different-places-in-storyboard-from-appdelegate) is actually the one I want.
this is sample code from him:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{        
    BOOL isLoggedIn = ...;    // from your server response

    NSString *segueId = isLoggedIn ? @"MainIdentifier" : @"LoginIdentifier";
    self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:segueId];

    return YES;
}
```

the way to set view controller identifier: [image]

I gave both @ekims and @X Slash a +1 for your inspiring discussion.
thank you guys sincerely.

Answer (score 3):

I would try putting the entire initialization of the view controller you want displayed into an if-else statement. You were setting `rootVC` to type `MainViewController` and then if the user had not logged in, trying to change `rootVC` to type `LoginViewController`

For example

```
id rootVC = nil;    
if (userNeverLogin) {
   rootVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
} else {
   rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
}

self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
```

**Update for view not displaying**

If you haven't created the method for initializing the view controller with the nib name (what others are suggesting you do), there is another workaround. Click  on your `MainViewController.xib` and in the Interface Builder click on `File Owner`. Click on the 3rd icon from the left in the utility side bar (right side of the screen), `Identity Inspector`, and change the custom class to `MainViewController`. Do the same thing for your `LoginViewController.xib`

Comment: I wrote my code as this in the beginning, but XCode would say the "rootVC" in the last line is an undeclared identifier. this code can not be compiled. I think the way X Slash uses is correct. However, I also want to know why XCode treats rootVC as "undeclared identifier" in this situation.

Comment: X Slash had the right approach, edited my answer to correct this problem

Comment: is there any way to achieve my goal without using xib? i am using storyboard, and I don't want to use xib if it's not necessary. thanks sincerely.

Comment: just open the storyboard and click on **MainViewController**, then click on **File Owner**. Same steps as listed above after that. (Identity Inspector -> change custom class)

Comment: I have found out the solution and answered the question by myself. Maybe you can have a look at the answer I posted. I hope the answer is also useful for you. thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

In your code,

```
MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
if (userNeverLogin) 
{
   LoginViewController *rootVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
}
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
```

rootVc will always be of MainViewController, because if the userNeverLogin is true, the rootVC inside that if block is for that if block scope only, so do something like

```
id rootViewController = nil;
if (userNeverLogin)
{
    rootViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];
}
else
{
    rootViewController = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
}
self.window.rootViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
```

Comment: thank you! now I can get NSLog from viewDidLoad in MainViewController, however, nothing appeared in the simulator. how should i fix this problem? (screen shot of simulator: http://cl.ly/image/1A1U1y0F1p04)
btw, I am using storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if your View loading from Nib.

```
 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];



        if (userNeverLogin) {
           LoginViewController *rootVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] nitwithNibName:@"LoginViewController" Bundle:nil];
        }
else
 MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initwithNibName:@"MainViewController" Bundle:nil];

    UINavigationcontroller *nvc= = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootVC];
        self.window.rootViewController=nvc;
        return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Deciding the root view controller in the App delegate should work.

I think what you missing is in

```
 MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
```

Try initializing the controller like this

```
 MainViewController *rootVC = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibFileName" bundle:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Follow this Steps:

1>keep your LoginView as a rootView       
2>In View viewDidAppear of LoginView check this
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   if ([User isLogin] == YES) {
   MainViewController *viewC = [[MainViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"EditStoreViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewC animated:YES];
}
```

}

this will solve your problem